# Splitting strings into multiple fixed width columns

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I am trying to use str_split to split the following observations into a specific format.

```
"00010943900008" "00010946803119" "00010946803219" "00010946803219" "00010946803219" "00010948700007"
```

I am trying to split it into different columns.

So that the first observation will look something like the following:

```
Column x = 00

Column y = 01

Column z = 09439

Column w = 00008
```

Where column x will always be the first 2 numbers in the observation, column y will be the next 2 numbers, column z will be the next 5 numbers and column w will be the final 5 numbers

Data

```
string <- c("00010943900008", "00010946803119", "00010946803219", "00010946803219", 
"00010946803219", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", 
"00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", 
"00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", 
"00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", 
"00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", 
"00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", 
"00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", 
"00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00010948700007", 
"00010948700007", "00010948700007", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", 
"00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016", "00011820000016"
)
```

Comment: I'd suggest writing it to a file then read it back in with `read.fwf`. Otherwise maybe use `substr`.

Answer (score 4):

You can either concatenate your data with `\n` as a separator or write it to file, then use `readr::read_fwf` or `read.fwf` (from file only) to import it as a fixed width format. Here's the `readr::read_fwf` version without writing to disk:

```
library(readr)
result = read_fwf(paste(string, collapse = "\n"),
                  col_positions = fwf_widths(c(2, 2, 5, 5), col_names = c("x", "y", "z", "w")))
head(result)
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   x     y     z     w
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 00    01    09439 00008
# 2 00    01    09468 03119
# 3 00    01    09468 03219
# 4 00    01    09468 03219
# 5 00    01    09468 03219
# 6 00    01    09487 00007
```

Comment: Using `textConnection` with `read.fwf` will work with a character string: `read.fwf(textConnection(string), widths = c(2,2,5,5), col_names = c("x", "y", "z", "w")`.

Answer (score 4):

With `extract` from `tidyr`. `extract` turns each regex capture group into its own column. If we don't want to keep the original column, we can set `remove = TRUE` (the default):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

string %>%
  data.frame(string = .) %>%
  extract(string, c("x","y","z","w"), "^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{5})(\\d{5})", remove = FALSE)
```

**Output:**

```
            string  x  y     z     w
1   00010943900008 00 01 09439 00008
2   00010946803119 00 01 09468 03119
3   00010946803219 00 01 09468 03219
4   00010946803219 00 01 09468 03219
5   00010946803219 00 01 09468 03219
6   00010948700007 00 01 09487 00007
7   00010948700007 00 01 09487 00007
8   00010948700007 00 01 09487 00007
9   00010948700007 00 01 09487 00007
10  00010948700007 00 01 09487 00007
11  00010948700007 00 01 09487 00007
12  00010948700007 00 01 09487 00007
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dataframe from the string, then use substr(), which returns part of strings based on position:

```
data<- as.data.frame(string)
data$x <- substr(string,1,2)
data$y <- substr(string,3,4)
data$z <- substr(string,5,9)
data$w <- substr(string,10,14)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `regex` and `read.table` (This will only work if the pattern is the same):

```
> read.table(text=gsub("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{5})(\\d{5})", "\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4", string),
             colClasses="character", sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    V1 V2    V3    V4
1   00 01 09439 00008
2   00 01 09468 03119
3   00 01 09468 03219
4   00 01 09468 03219
5   00 01 09468 03219
6   00 01 09487 00007
7   00 01 09487 00007
8   00 01 09487 00007
9   00 01 09487 00007
10  00 01 09487 00007
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *tidyr::separate*:

```
library(tidyr)

data.frame(string = string[1:5]) %>% 
  separate(string, c("x", "y", "z", "w"),
           sep = c(2, 4, 9), remove = FALSE)

#           string  x  y     z     w
# 1 00010943900008 00 01 09439 00008
# 2 00010946803119 00 01 09468 03119
# 3 00010946803219 00 01 09468 03219
# 4 00010946803219 00 01 09468 03219
# 5 00010946803219 00 01 09468 03219
```